# Can i use single derby database for two different derby network server?

Tags: spring-boot, derby

> I am working with spring boot and derby database.
>
> I want to use single derby database i.e (location:"c://DerbyDB") to two different port i.e 8888 , 4444.
>
> How can i give write access to both server ?`
>   Anyone have idea ,please help me.

Comment: I don't believe the Derby Network Server can do this directly; it only opens a single listening socket to accept connections, and that socket is bound to a single port. However, it seems like this should be possible using a port-forwarding tool or proxy of some sort. For example, have you tried placing an SSH tunnel in front of the Derby Network Server, listening on 4444 and forwarding to 8888?

Comment: **Bryan Pandleton** I dont know about SSH tunnel .Can you elaborate?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol#Secure_Shell_tunneling